# assign a button be a word in a wordlist

Tags: python, list, tkinter, button

I am making this Rock Paper Scissors game based on just image buttons to resemble rock paper scissors.

But now i want to assign a button to be "Rock" from my list.
How would i do that?
code:

```
    #Options
def Game():
    choice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    RockButton = choice[0]
    PaperButton = choice[1]
    ScissorsButton = choice[2]

    #Naming the images
RockButton = Button(root, image = rock, bg="white", bd=0,command=Game).pack(side = LEFT)
PaperButton = Button(root, image = paper, bg="white", bd=0,command=Game).pack(side = RIGHT)
ScissorsButton = Button(root, image = scissors, bg="white", bd=0, command=Game).pack(pady=10)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is this related to the user interface, using a python list, or the `game` function?

Comment: Python list yeah

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify things by using lambda functions for the `command` parameter of each button instead of using `Game` directly.

```
def Game(player_choice_string):
    print("player chose: {}".format(player_choice_string))

(RockButton := Button(root, image = rock, bg="white", bd=0,command=lambda:Game("rock"))).pack(side = LEFT)
(PaperButton := Button(root, image = paper, bg="white", bd=0,command=lambda:Game("paper"))).pack(side = RIGHT)
(ScissorsButton := Button(root, image = scissors, bg="white", bd=0, command=lambda:Game("scissors"))).pack(pady=10)
```

The walrus operator (`:=`) works in python >= 3.8
For older versions, you can just split the `Button()` and `.pack()` call onto two lines as shown here: [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Comment: I don't think the `.format` is going to work properly without the `{}`. Also can you please fix [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1101750/11106801) before it becomes a problem.

Comment: A question, how would i build a computer enemy w this

Comment: @trapgrave Stack overflow is not meant for very general questions such as "how would I build a computer enemy with this". You will have to try some options on your own, and come back with any specific/technical questions. Either way, if you like the answer, can you make sure to upvote and accept the answer (check mark).